# JS OOPS better understanding

Tags: javascript

I just learing oops in Js. I know the simple js inheritance. the following code just clientUser extends user and he can access User function. because I just copy the reference obj from user thorough object.create(). from now I can understand only the following simple code

```js
function User(a,n){
this.name=n;
this.age=a;
}

User.prototype.getters= function(){
 document.write (`name is ${this.name} and age is ${this.age}****`)
}

john = new User('john-smith', 18);
john.getters();

function ClientUser(a,n,i){
 User.call(this,a,n);
}

ClientUser.prototype = Object.create(User.prototype)
c = new ClientUser('groot',23,'smalID');
c.getters();
```

the code produced by CoffeeScript

```
<!-- language: cofeee -->

class Bear
  constructor: (@name) ->

  attack: ->
    "#{@name} the bear attacks with his bare paws!"

//oswalt = new Bear "Oswalt"
rodrigo = new BearWithChainsawHands "Rodrigo"
//console.log rodrigo.attack()
console.log oswalt.attack()
```

I just try to understand the behind process of this code. i know in CoffeeScript it is working like super(). but I can't understand the code in js.

```js
var Bear, BearWithChainsawHands, rodrigo;
var __hasProp = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;
var __extends = function(child, parent) {
  for (var key in parent) {
    if (__hasProp.call(parent, key)) {
     debugger;
     console.log(key)
      child[key] = parent[key];
    }
    else{
      debugger
    }
  }
  function ctor() { this.constructor = child; }

  ctor.prototype = parent.prototype;
  child.prototype = new ctor;
  child.__super__ = parent.prototype;

  return child;
};

function Bear(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

Bear.prototype.attack = function() {
  return "" + this.name + " the bear attacks with his bare paws!";
};

function BearWithChainsawHands() {
  BearWithChainsawHands.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
}

__extends(BearWithChainsawHands, Bear);

BearWithChainsawHands.prototype.attack = function() {
  return BearWithChainsawHands.__super__.attack.apply(this, arguments) + " BY THE WAY, HIS PAWS ARE CHAINSAWS.";
};

rodrigo = new BearWithChainsawHands("Rodrigo");
console.log(rodrigo.attack());
document.write(rodrigo.attack())
```

anyone can explain the usage of __extend()'s work? and code flow?

Comment: It will copy all the enumerable own properties to child

Comment: ctor.prototype = parent.prototype;
  child.prototype = new ctor;
  child.__super__ = parent.prototype why this lines?

Comment: Most of that code is autogenerated by the Coffeescript transpiler and not necessary in the example at all.

Comment: Your CoffeeScript code doesn't contain any `BearWithChainsawHands`?

Comment: @Bergi edited  now

Comment: my question how is it working inheritance without using object.create()

Comment: @SelvaGanapathi This might help you: https://medium.com/@rlynjb/js-interview-question-explain-how-prototypal-inheritance-works-7537f98b8cd2

Comment: @SelvaGanapathi Ah, that's the question. It doesn't use `Object.create` because that's not available in pre-ES5 (ancient) browsers, instead it uses `new ctor` where `ctor` is a constructor created only to instantiate one object with the desired prototype.

Comment: @SelvaGanapathi See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12785036/1048572 for example